# CSS animation for both mouse hover and touch (iOS)

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari

Here is [plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/W47h7jaFeUHc3cCYRmbs?p=preview).

Basically there is a style like that

```
.hover-block {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
            transition: all 1s linear;      

}

.hover-block:active {
  pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
            transform: scale(1.5);
}

.hover-block:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
            transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

I'm seeking to support evergreen and IE10/11, Chrome for Android (4.4+), Mobile Safari (iOS 7+), and it shouldn't hurt other touch events (swipe scrolling).

It seems to work as intended on Android and Chrome device emulation, non-sticky transform on touch is desired behaviour.

But somehow this plunker doesn't work on iOS webkit (iOS 8, all browsers), it does nothing on touch. I'm quite sure that exactly the same approach (block element, `:active` with `pointer-events: none` plus `:hover`) worked for me in iOS 8 before. How can it be fixed?

---

It looks like *empty* touchstart/touchend JS event handler or `ontouchstart`/`ontouchend` attribute [can activate touch behaviour on iOS](http://plnkr.co/edit/FKngSXlZpda2VZVKnHQE?p=preview) (can't be sure but it is possible that it happened to me before). Is it a known fix for the problem or there are less hacky ones, which iOS versions are affected?

Comment: Does :focus do anything?

Comment: @BillyNate No, there's no change.

Comment: I think there is no better solution for your situation(.

Comment: If adding an empty touchstart event handler fixes your problem adding `cursor: pointer;` to the element will solve it as well. Still hacky, but with less JS.

Comment: @pstenstrm Thanks, I'm aware of `cursor: pointer` hack, it never worked for me as advertised, but please post an answer if you've got a field-tested example.

Comment: Have to use `ontouchstart` to fire the `:active` trigger in CSS for iOS Webkit.  Sorry.  Posted that as an answer and then saw your second section.  Apologies.

Comment: Right so why dont you just disable the hover effect's using media queries and reactivate pointer event's so that focus and active work again when the person presses the object?

Comment: @DCdaz I don't think it will work as intended (non-sticky animation on both desktop and iOS). If you have iOS device at hand to make sure it works the right way, please, post an answer.

Comment: @estus sorry dont have one to hand not in the studio today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue you're running into is this: "The [`:active` pseudo class matches when an element is being activated by the user](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)". A standalone `<div>` element cannot be activated by the user and therefore will not be matched by the `:active` pseudo class.

If you look under [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aactive#Browser_compatibility) in the `:active` MDN article you'll see that:

> [1] By default, Safari Mobile does not use the :active state unless there is a `touchstart` event handler on the relevant element or on the `<body>`.

MDN has a [list of pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) that can be used and you might be able to find one that better fits your situation or adding a `touchstart` event should do the trick in Safari.

I was able to get your plnkr working really quick by changing the `<div class="hover-block"></div>` element to `<button class="hover-block"></button>` and changing `.hover-block:active {` to `.hover-block:focus {`. I also added `display: block; border: 0;` to `.hover-block`.

You, for obvious reasons, may not want to change your `<div>` to a `<button>` to get your effect to work, but by using an element that can be activated, using a different pseudo class, or adding an event that allows activation in your target browser, you should be able to achieve the effect you're looking for on mobile devices.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So this is expected behaviour and not a hack. [Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/input/touch/activestates/index#enabling-active-state-support-on-ios) states that it is required for buttons too. Do you have an idea why they did it? Is it `:focus` in your example that should make a difference?

Comment: Sorry, no, I have no idea why they did it this way, checking the spec may provide more background information on that. I only used :focus in my example since it was quick and dirty way to achieve the desired effect and it was easy to illustrate on both desktop and mobile. I would probably opt for :active and touchstart in your situation.

Answer (score 4):

In your html, instead of `<body>`, do `<body ontouchstart="">`
Or in html5, just `<body ontouchstart>`

Comment: I've accepted an answer a few minutes ago, but it looks like a great answer as well. It seems that it can fix touch for all page elements.